# QGIS 3.4: error when cutting raster ("Cannot compute bounding box of cutline")

Tags: raster, qgis-3

QGIS 3.4

During the process of trimming raster layers, the command failed. 
Looking at the Journal, the root error seems to be :

> ERROR 1: Cannot compute bounding box of cutline. Cannot find source SRS

However, I have defined an CRS for each layout, and it is also shown in the windows selection.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my observation, this behaviour occured only for geroreferenced JPEG raster.
Even if a CRS is defined in QGIS, this piece of information is not transfered in the command line. (I had also tried Raster > Projection  > Assign a CRS, but with no change)

To circumvent this issue, I copied the gdalwarp command shown in the GDAL/OGR command Console (at the end of the windows shown upper), and add the following option

```
-s-srs EPSG 2154
```

The full command line looks like:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -s_srs EPSG:2154 -tr 21.16575950653999 -21.16717538698448 -tap -cutline sia_N.gpkg -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 -co ZLEVEL=9 2019_N.jpg /tmp/OUTPUT.tif
```

Comment: Do you think you found a bug in QGIS? You can make a bug report here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues